# Collision detection not working in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two 2D game objects. They each have a Box Collider 2D and a Rigid Body 2D which is not kinematic. When the game plays, one moves towards the other and collides with it.

However, I also have the following method in the moving GameObject:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) 
{
    print( "Collided with someone" );
}
```

The print statement never prints, so presumably the method is never called. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you confirm that your class inherits from [MonoBehaviour](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html)? Change Scripting reference to C# in the docs. A question about game-development can best be asked here: [gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I haven't checked, but there is a [`OnCollisionEnter2D`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) which you have to use. This has caught me out when I was converting a 2D game to their 2D framework...

Comment: Ah! That was it, thanks T. Kiley =)

Comment: Not to be *that guy* but could you accept then, thanks :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Unity has replicated all of the physics methods for 2D with the word "2D" stuck onto the end! So for your example, it should be changed to:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
```

And the same with basically any other 2D physics thing.